# If $x<2,|x-2|=y$ and $xy=1$ ,what is the value of $x^2+y^2$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I try to solve it in the following way
\begin{align*} 
|x-2| &=  y \\ 
\sqrt{(x-2)^2} &=  y\\
(x-2)^2 &=  y^2\\
x^2-4x+4&=y^2\\
\end{align*}
but I don't know what else to do to get to the value of $x^2+y^2$ and I don't know how to use xy=1

Answer (score 4):

If $x < 2$, then $y = |x - 2| = 2 - x$. Hence we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + y^{2} = (x + y)^{2} - 2xy = 2^{2} - 2 = 2.
\end{align*}